# ¿Cómo puedo indicar en un bucle for cuando se encuentre con x, imprima el valor siguiente?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo una lista con diccionarios, necesito que cuando se encuentre el valor :'qualifier_id':"130", imprima el valor, pero de la clave value.

así es la lista:

```
 {'id': '1518776786',
  'qualifier_id': '227',
  'value': '0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'},
 {'id': '997025056',
  'qualifier_id': '59',
  'value': '25, 2, 13, 18, 4, 6, 42, 7, 10, 16, 21, 5, 11, 15, 20, 22, 32, 45'}]
```

tengo el siguiente código:

```
  coordenadafinalx=[]
  coordenadafinaly=[]

  for elem1 in listaq:
      for ka, va in elem1.items():
        if ka == 'qualifier_id' and va == "140":
            coordenadafinalx.append(va)
```

Solo me queda indicar que es lo que imprimir, en vez de va, sería el siguiente valor , o sea un 4.Siempre que se cumpla la condición.

Comment: La pregunta es incongruente. Quieres seleccionar por "130", pero el código dice "140" y los datos cualquier otra cosa. Hablas de imprimir y no se ve donde estás imprimiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Utilizando el siguiente diccionario:

```
# Diccionario
d = {'id': '2028397186', 'qualifier_id': '130', 'value': '4'}
```

Lo que se me ocurre es primero obtener una lista con las llaves del diccionario, iterar con un `for` hasta encontrar la llave que buscas y obtener el índice numérico de esa llave.

```
llaves.index(k)
```

Si sumamos `1` a ese índice numérico entonces obtendríamos la siguiente llave

```
llaves[llaves.index(k)+1]
```

Esto devolvería la llave `value` y podemos utilizar ese nombre de llave en el diccionario original para obtener el valor que buscas

```
d[llaves[llaves.index(k)+1]]
```

Explicación:

La sección `llaves.index(k)` contiene el índice numérico de la llave `qualifier_id` que sería `1` al sumarle `1` entonces tenemos `2`, por lo que `llaves[llaves.index(k)+1]` se reduce a `llaves[2]` que vendría siendo `value`, por lo que `d[llaves[llaves.index(k)+1]]` se reduce a `d['value']` que devuelve `4`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
d = {'id': '2028397186', 'qualifier_id': '130', 'value': '4'}

llaves = list(d)

for k in llaves:
    if k == 'qualifier_id':
        print(d[llaves[llaves.index(k)+1]])
```

Esto imprime `4`.

### Edición:

Al agregar información resulta que no es un diccionario sino una lista de diccionarios y solo se debe obtener el valor de `value` cuando `qualifier_id` sea igual a `140`

Por lo que adaptando el código anterior quedaría así:

```
ld = [{'id': '2028397186', 'qualifier_id': '130', 'value': '4'},
      {'id': '1518776786', 'qualifier_id': '227', 'value': '0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'},
      {'id': '997025056', 'qualifier_id': '59', 'value': '25, 2, 13, 18, 4, 6, 42, 7, 10, 16, 21, 5, 11, 15, 20, 22, 32, 45'},
      {'id': '955425655', 'qualifier_id': '140', 'value': '17476'}]

for d in ld:
    llaves = list(d)
    for k in llaves:
        if k == 'qualifier_id' and d[k] == '140':
            print(d[llaves[llaves.index(k)+1]])
```

Esto imprime

```
17476
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero la verdad me he expresado yo mal...En realidad solo se tendría que imprimir cuando ka == 'qualifier_id' and va == "140":...y el realidad es en lista de diccionarios con esta forma:[{'id': '2028397186', 'qualifier_id': '130', 'value': '4'},
 {'id': '1518776786',
  'qualifier_id': '227',
  'value': '0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'},
 {'id': '997025056',
  'qualifier_id': '59',
  'value': '25, 2, 13, 18, 4, 6, 42, 7, 10, 16, 21, 5, 11, 15, 20, 22, 32, 45'},
 {'id': '955425655', 'qualifier_id': '194', 'value': '17476'}]

Comment: @susanaruizmolero, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información relevante, además, la lista de diccionarios que muestra no tiene ningún `140` por lo que tampoco es válida...

Comment: @susanaruizmolero, ya edité la respuesta. Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: ya he editado la pregunta